# $broadcast not being picked up in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a simple service/factory:

```
angular.module('myapp').factory('User', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        hello: function() {
            console.log('Sending root scope message');
            $rootScope.$broadcast('saidhello', {greeting: 'hey'});
        }
    };
}]);
```

In my controller, I simply call the hello method: `User.hello()`, which logs my console message.

I'd like to pick this up in a directive, but it doesn't seem to work...

```
angular.module('myapp').directive('user', ['User', function(User) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: true,
        link: ['scope', 'element', 'attrs', function(scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$on('saidhello', function(event, data) {
                console.log('User said ' + data.greeting);
            });
        }]
    }
}]);
```

Nothing is logged... I've tried wrapping the broadcast in a timeout to make sure the directive is loaded but no joy. Also tried `$emit` instead of `$broadcast`.

My HTML is like so:

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <!-- Used to execute service -->
    </div>
    <user></user>
</body>
```

Comment: I believe you have to inject `$rootScope` into your directive to catch those events.

Comment: if you call that directly in controller ... directive hasn't even been processed yet...so there is nothing there to catch the event. Controllers have to run before directives in order to create scope that will be used by directives

Comment: @charlietfl Ah I see - I am calling it straight away! However wrapping it in a "on click" handler doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: One other thing that will cause a problem, after you make fix charlie's (entirely correct) suggested fix, is that directives `link` functions do not allow dependency injection. As in, the `link` property doesn't work with an Array, at least not in v1.3.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link should be a function, shouldn't it? Rather than an array, since its parameters are static.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

    scope.$on('saidhello', function(event, data) {
        console.log('User said ' + data.greeting);
    });

    // say hello
    User.hello();
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Shj112rfu6dyTcUHPVfM?p=preview

Comment: Bajesus that worked - I thought it was for when the code was minified (do it in controllers). That made it work :D

Comment: It is, but that's for injected resources. In the link function you can't inject resources; they're always the same, so minification won't cause any problems.

Answer (score 0):

The issue boils down to the fact that controllers must run before the DOM can be compiled in order to create scope needed for the view.

By calling an event immediately in controller you are calling it before the listener in directive has been attached.

By the time listener has been attached the event is already over

Comment: This answer is correct, and outlines the problem. Though, semantically, I don't think that in this case it really _needs_ to run and create the scope first, since the `user` directive is outside of the `ngController` node, so doesn't have access to the scope anyway. Though there is another good reasons why the controller should execute first (for its DOM node appears first! Reorder the nodes, and this is no longer the case.)

Comment: @DRobinson really not clear what you are saying ... ng-controller will fire before directives was the point

Comment: What I'm saying is "not necessarily". You're assuming that the directive's DOM element is contained in the controller's, but that isn't the case in the question (they're shown instead to be siblings). Here's an example fiddle to illustrate: http://jsfiddle.net/k9s5wnt7/1/ . The first directive catches the `bananas` broadcast, and says "Yummy!", but the one that comes after does not. This is because Angular is building these in the order that they're presented.

Comment: ok..i did miss that it wasn't a child but in this case what i stated is still true

Comment: Right, and so my original comment says that (in this case) you are correct. But making the assumption that the controller always runs before the directives is inaccurate. Stating that it _has to_ run first is misleading. Again, I agree with your assessment - it is correct in this case - but it could cause confusion, hence the comment.

Comment: Essentially, you're right about the order that these particular elements will be executed but the generalized statement in your answer, "controllers must run before the DOM can be compiled", isn't necessarily true. My fiddle in the above comment, http://jsfiddle.net/k9s5wnt7/1/ , demonstrates the DOM being compiled, and a directive being linked, before the controller is run.